# How to configure SPF Record in DNS to allow Google Apps Gmail and my website host to also send mail properly?

Tags: email, record, configure, spf

I use Google Apps (gmail) for my business.   I also host my own web server which has forums and other things that require email validations and registration.  So I have configured my DNS SPF record to approve Google's mail servers and I need to also allow mail to be send from my hosts mail server so that it isn't considered spam.  I am not new to this but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.  This hosts doesn't receive mail for my domain but just sends out mail.  Here is what my current SPF record is and what I think it "should" be.  I have tried several different ways, but it doesn't seem to correct my problem.

v=spf1 ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx include:_spf.google.com ~all

I have put it in as an SPF and TXT and as both at the same time.  But doesn't seem to correct it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Forgot to add that it does have correct and valid PTR Record.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11442044/488489